# Why is screen clipping slow on windows?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, screenshot

I have recently switched back to windows from Ubuntu.

I am having problems with the in-built screenshot clipping tool activated by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Although it works the way I want it to, and similar to the in-built Ubuntu screen clipping tool, it can be very slow.

If I make a screen clipping I have to wait for a few seconds before I am able to paste the results.

I haven't noticed anything else being slow and I have a relatively new laptop.

Why would this be? Is there some alternative tool which is still simple but more reliable for windows?

Comment: Using shift + win + s just puts it straight onto the clipboard, rather than showing you a preview in the snipping tool. This for me works very quickly, with seemingly the only lag in how long it takes me to ctrl+v into mspaint.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes, for me there is a long lag, up to a few seconds where if I press ctrl v it will just paste the previous item in the clipboard

Comment: Win+PrintScreen would be faster if you don't need to crop right away

Comment: @phuclv i would like to crop right away - do you know why it would be slow, and what would be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

I've put up with this for long enough.  I've tried many solutions and read way to much about something that used to work 3+ years ago just fine!

I was taking a UDEMY course and wanted to capture a picture for my notes and it took 11 seconds for the screen capture to decide to work!!!

I just switch to https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/ to get back my life.
I donated 5 bucks just because I was happy to have something that works again.

I'm a software developer and regularly have to use screenshots to capture issues I've run into with my software development and UI issues that are sometimes not reproducible so you have to capture the issue when you see it.

Greenshot is my solution for Windows + Shift + S slowness.

Sorry this is so NOT an answer but it is my answer until Microsoft fix this (and given that it's been a couple years) I'm guessing they don't find this as a problem.